# Building a data frame row by row from a list

Tags: json, r, dataframe

I am parsing a data structure that looks like this in R:

```
[
  { 'firstName': 'abc', 'lastName' : 'def' },
  { 'firstName': 'abc2', 'lastName' : 'def2' }
]
```

I want to store this data in a data frame. My current approach is flawed and feels really messy. I have several data sets, but need to specify the columns. Can anyone suggest something 'cleaner'?

**Problem 1: I need to specify the data names**

```
library(rjson)
listData <- fromJSON(jsonData)
listNames <- c('firstName', 'lastName')

for (player in listData){
  playerCols = c()
  for (name in listNames){
    value <- player[[name]]
    if (is.null(value}{value <- "NA"}
    playerCols <- c(playerCols, value)
  }
  # code to convert playerCols to data.frame currently goes here. 
}
```

I would like to run this extraction if possible without using the column names, or in such a way that I extract the columns from that data as I go along. The tricky part here is that not all columns are populated in each entry. I'd like the final data frame to know all columns and set missing values to `NA`

**Problem 2: I seem to fail adding a row of data, instead the lists are created as columns**

```
for (player in listData){
  # code to extract columns here
  df = data.frame(playerCols, name=listNames)
  print(df)
}
```

Instead of creating a 2 column data frame with rows that contain all the data and all the names, I want a single row, with named columns, that I can then `rbind` together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's almost always a bad idea to try to build a data.frame row-by-row. It's just not an efficient process. It's better to build your data column by column and the combine into a data.frame at the end. First, let's use some sample data that actually has missing values as you describe

```
a<-'[
  { "firstName": "abc", "lastName" : "def" },
  { "firstName": "abc2" }
]'
```

Let's also build a helper function that will extract a value from a list if it exists, or will return NA if it does not

```
extr<-function(list,ele) {
    x<-list[[ele]]
    if (is.null(x)) x=NA;
    x
}
```

If you want to grab all the values without having to specify the tag names explicitly, you can find them using

```
listNames <- unique(unlist(lapply(listData, names)))
```

Now we can convert the json to a list, and then extract a vector of column values each time and then finally combine them into a data.frame with

```
listData <- fromJSON(a)
data.frame(Map(function(n) sapply(listData, extr, n), listNames))
```

Here i use `Map` rather than the more customary `lapply` because it will properly use the values of `listNames` as names for the returned list.

Comment: Perfect that worked with one exception - `c(sapply(listData, names))` instead of using `unlist`